# Tiger Client Bound to Leopard Open Directory Server

Tags: osx-leopard, opendirectory, tiger, mcx

I am trying to get my tiger clients to bind to an open directory server on leopard.

I am able to bind the computer to the directory and when I look in Workgroup Manager the computer shows up correctly but none of the settings show up on the client.  If I attempt to unbind the client from Directory Access on the client it removes but the client pops up a message that it "Could not contact the LDAP server to unbind.  Would you like to forcibly remove this configuration?".

I am able to get leopard clients to bind successfully and pull down their settings (OD servers themselves are pulling login window changes).

If (while bound) I use dscl and attempt to cd into the OD I receive a message that the path is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

When I ran into this problem a couple of weeks ago, the Tiger computer was bound to the Leopard directory server by IP address, and, as you said, when I `cd`ed into the appropriate LDAP subfolder using `dscl`, I got an error message -- most likely an invalid directory.  I forcibly unbound and rebound the computer using a DNS name instead of an IP.  [Why this makes any sense is beyond me.]  I could then `cd` into the directory using `dscl`, but the computer was still not allowing network users to log in.

I found the answer to that problem in this thread
http://lists.apple.com/archives/macos-x-server/2007/Dec/msg00316.html

Basically, I needed to edit `/etc/hostconfig` and change

```
AUTOMOUNT=-YES-
```

to

```
AUTOMOUNT=-NO-.
```